# Service.startForeground() forces the notification to be ongoing, is there a workaround?

Tags: android

When I show a notification via `service.startForeground(id, notification)`, the notification is set to be ongoing, which makes the app cumbersome to use. Is there a workaround to make a foreground notification non-ongoing so that it can be easily swiped away?

If not, I guess I would have to choose between using a background service or adding a "dismiss" action to the notification, which already contains some actions.

Comment: no you cant do this . the foreground notification until you call `stopForeground()` in the service cant be remove.

Comment: Damn. That sucks.

Comment: yes . and in android O and above is worst that you cant use background service without notification and you must use foreground service instead !! https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Yeah I know... :/ what's your use case?

Comment: using `JobSchulder`  for periodic task. and for task that need long time to finish using `ForegroundService`